# Sharing a master between MVC and WebForms - dealing with the <form>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

We have a large legacy application where we want to start using MVC for new functionality.

To do this we added custom routing, for instance:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute( "{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.as[pmh]x(/.*)?" } );
```

And we want to share the master page between the old WebForms and the new MVC pages.

This seems simple enough - changed the master to inherit from `ViewMasterPage` and it can be used as the master for MVC pages too.

The problem is the HTML `<form>`.

The master page has a `<form>` tag at the top and 3 content panels inside it, which is how WebForms like it. The `Page` control overrides the master's form to point back at the page, and this appears to be a hardcoded behaviour.

All three content panels have WebForms controls, so the page level `<form>` tag needs to be outside them to cover all three. Something like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    ...
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="content1" runat="server" />
    ...
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="content2" runat="server" />
    ... //etc
</form>
```

However, for MVC we want to have forms inside the views using the `Html.BeginForm` helper. HTML doesn't let you nest forms. MVC pattern needs the views to post back to different actions (for instance a "details" view might post back to an "edit" action).

Does anyone know a good way around this?

Comment: I'm aware of this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841418 Here I'm specifically concerned with the issue of the form tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We share a master page between web forms and MVC which doesn't have the `<form>`. You can create an intermediate master page for web forms which in turn uses your root master page, but adds the `<form>`. The hierarchical structure of master pages is very useful for these constructs.

Comment: This is basically what I did in the end - have a common.master with some of the layout, and then an MVC.master and a WebForms.master

Comment: Do you have any examples I can see? I think I'm getting all turned around.