# Ideas to improve/enrich a WebForms application by adding ASP.NET MVC elements to it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, refactoring

I'm currently present with the following situation.

We have a huge enterprise application written with WebForms. Refactoring it or completely rewriting it is out of the question. So I'm not talking about migration WebForms -> MVC.

However, I understand one can technically add MVC functionality to coexist with the rest of the project. I was asked to present MVC concepts for a team so that we can consider how it could become (or not) of use to us.

After careful thinking I do not see any ways or reasons to add MVC elements to a WebForms project since it will become a strange breed then.

Maybe there are certain not exactly obvious possibilities to add value to a WebForms project with MVC framework? Has anybody thought about it?

Answer (score 3):

- [Sharing a master between MVC and WebForms - dealing with the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031252/sharing-a-master-between-mvc-and-webforms-dealing-with-the-form)
- [Mixing ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC](https://hub.packtpub.com/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc/)
- [ASP.NET MVC WebForms Hybrid application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/)
- *Combining MVC and WebForms* from [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20110112152618/http://apress.com/book/view/9781430210078) (also available [here](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-1-4302-1008-5?from=SL))

Answer (score 1):

I would also look at this article from Scott Hanselman.  He seems to have the mojo on mixing these technologies.

[Plug in Hybrids...Mixing ASP.NET and ...](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx)