# Is it possible to use MVC Controllers for ASP.NET Web Application with Web Forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web, webforms, authorization

I'm making an application which needs a secure authorization system. I created a simple login system reading columns on a database with some 50 lines of C# code but I need complexity and the application needs to be secure.

Is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 0):

Combining web forms with MVC is entirely possible.check this answer [Combine ASP.Net MVC with WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203467/4846123)