# Redirect Asp.net Web form to Mvc View vise vars

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I am working on project in that some pages are in Web Form (Asp.net) and some pages are in MVC (Asp.net MVC view)

I want to navigate Web From to Mvc View & vise versa

Project Structure

[image]

I want to redirect Asp.net Master page to Mvc Controller

[image]

Redirection coder is bellow,

[image]

It will not working ,How can I achieve this functionality

Comment: As you are trying to redirect to another project, you need to provide whole path.Currently it is not able to hit the index method of adduser controller because it is placed in another project.

Comment: how can I achieve it i am not able to understand

Comment: If there any way to combine asp.net [web form] & asp.net [MVC] application in single project ?

Comment: yes you can combine both projects in single project you just need to placeyour controller folder in web form project and need to add references for MVC in that project. It wil work. If you don't want to do that then please specify whole path in href link like href="localhost:3456//adduser/index" something like that.

Comment: Yes that I do it , I add Mvc project reference in web form project , but my concern is that how can I call mvc view from web form

Comment: You can visit below link.There is very clear explanation there.Check and let us know if it helps you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203411/combine-asp-net-mvc-with-webforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to write razor view syntax in webforms which is not going to work.

You can combine both webforms and MVC in a single project.

[image]

```
<a href="~/WebForm1.aspx">Redirect to Webform</a>
```

in your MVC view to redirect to webforms.

and

```
<a href="Home/Index">Redirect Now</a>
```

from webfroms to MVC

Comment: "The resource cannot be found" :- error come with this senario

Comment: It is possible to combine aspx [asp.net] master page use in mvc [ view ] ? user common master page for aspx & mvc

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use "user control" in both WebForms and MVC, as both use different view engine (aspx view engine and razor view engine).

Comment: You can visit below link.There is very clear explanation there.Check and let us know if it helps you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203411/combine-asp-net-mvc-with-webforms