# c#, IIS 10, Web Forms, Forms Authentication, Bootstrap 4, Web API, Trying to Add Signalr - getting 404 on signalr/hubs?

Tags: webforms, asp.net-web-api2, forms-authentication, iis-10, signalr-2

I've used each of the title technologies individually before. It's combining them that's become the issue.

Web App works perfectly on Dev machine with IIS Express (Visual Studio 2019).

When I publish, no SignalR.  if I try to navigate to webaddress.com/signalr/hubs I get a 404 error.

the #1 fix:  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`

- this "fixes" Signalr.  but then there is no bootstrap on the pages and the `<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />` to fix the URL without Default.aspx, gets broken as well.

So I'm guessing there is a "module" that i have to use to get Signalr to work again and the "run allmanagedmodules" is too generic?

Here's my Web Config.  Any Ideas?

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="XXXXXXXXX.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="XXXXXXXXXX" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXXXX\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;Integrated Security=false;user=XXXXXXX;password=XXXXXXX" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" defaultUrl="default.aspx" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="signalr">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Patient.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="aboutus.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="contact.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="iforgot.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="test.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="api/XXXX">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <applicationSettings>
    <XXXXXXX.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="UserID" serializeAs="String">
        <value>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FromEmail" serializeAs="String">
        <value>XXXXXXX@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="EmailUsername" serializeAs="String">
        <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="EmailPassword" serializeAs="String">
        <value>XXXXXXXXXX</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="EmailServer" serializeAs="String">
        <value>mail.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Token" serializeAs="String">
        <value>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</value>
      </setting>
    </XXXXXXX.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules >
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />

      <!-- any other modules you want to run in MVC e.g. FormsAuthentication, Roles etc. -->

    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The title is too vague. I suggest you start from a sample app and then see what's the problem. You need to pinpoint the issue before posting here.

Comment: The problem is all the technologies together.  A "Sample App" would be the App! If i pinpointed the issue it would literally be the fix.

Comment: combine mvc and webform [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203411/combine-asp-net-mvc-with-webforms)