# Merge MVC development in existing Asp.net Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to one help

I have 1 Webform application which is in the Asp.Net and it is working fine and now I want to develop new functionality in Asp.Net MVC and merge in existing application.

So please provide any tutorial or any link which provide information for merging MVC functionality in existing Asp.Net application.

Basically I need to develop application which working with both Asp.net webform functionality and also MVC functionality.

Comment: Which version of Webforms and MVC you are targeting? And also which version of VS you have?

Comment: FW - 4, VS - 2010 , MVC - 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Combining web forms with MVC is entirely possible. See [this blog post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) for an introduction.

- Sharing master pages: [see this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841418/is-it-possible-to-share-a-masterpage-between-mvc-and-webforms)
- routing: In ASP.Net 4.0, [routing has been enabled for web forms page routes (scottgu's blog)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)